# divisibility relation $a|b^2 + 10c.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Use divisibility relation to show that for all integer  $a$, $b$, $c$, $a \ne 0$ counts if $a|b$ and $a|c$ then $a|b^2 + 10c$.

Use direct proof.

Ok,

$a|6$ then there is integer $k$.
 $$a*k=6,$$
 $$a*k1=6  , $$ 
 $$a*k2=c$$
 $$ b^2+10c=a*k3$$

then? :/

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$.  By definition this means that
$$b=ax\quad\hbox{and}\quad c=ay$$
for some integers $x$ and $y$.  Therefore
$$b^2+10c=(ax)^2+10(ay)=a(ax^2+10y)\ .$$
But $ax^2+10y$ is an integer (as it is a sum of products of integers): let's call it $z$.  Therefore $b^2+10c=az$, where $z$ is an integer.  By definition this means
$$a\mid b^2+10c\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

it is staightly follow as  a|b  imply a|b^2  and 
 a| c imply a| 10c  and further "  as we know if x|y and x|z then x| x+z  "  by using this we can directly conclude that a | b^2 + 10c.